# How to give interactions to a bar in a bar graph i.e. increase and decrease of height of each bar in android without using any library

Tags: android

I am able to plot bar graph using canvas and drawing rectangle in the view. But the `onTouch` interaction works for the whole view and hence I am not able to interact with each bar separately.I am not looking for using any library for plotting graphs. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float border = 20;
    float horstart = border * 2;
    float height = getHeight();
    float width = getWidth() - 1;
    float max = getMax();
    float min = getMin();
    float diff = max - min;
    float graphheight = height - (2 * border);
    float graphwidth = width - (2 * border);



    paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
    int vers = verlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < verlabels.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        float y = ((graphheight / vers) * i) + border;
        //canvas.drawLine(horstart, y, width, y, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawText(verlabels[i], 0, y, paint);
    }
    int hors = horlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < horlabels.length; i++) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
        //canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        if (i == horlabels.length - 1)
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        if (i == 0)
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x, height - 4, paint);
    }

    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(title, (graphwidth / 2) + horstart, border - 4, paint);

    if (max != min) {

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        if (type == BAR) {
            float datalength = values.length;
            float colwidth = (graphwidth / hors);
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                float val = values[i] - min;
                float rat = val / diff;
                float h = graphheight * rat;

                canvas.drawRect((i * colwidth) + horstart, (border - h)
                        + graphheight+curY, ((i * colwidth) + horstart)
                        + (colwidth - 1), height - (border - 1), paint);



            }
        } else {
            float datalength = values.length;
            float colwidth = (width - (2 * border)) / datalength;
            float halfcol = colwidth / 2;
            float lasth = 0;
            float h = 0;
            for (int i = 0;i<values.length;i++)
                    canvas.drawLine(((i - 1) * colwidth) + (horstart + 1)
                            + halfcol, (border - lasth) + graphheight+curY,
                            (i * colwidth) + (horstart + 1) + halfcol,
                            (border - h) + graphheight, paint);
                lasth = h;
            }
        }
    }
```

onTouch method for the view :

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
         boolean result=false;
        switch (event.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                curX= (int)event.getX();
                curY= (int)event.getY();

                result=true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                curX= (int)event.getX();
                curY= (int)event.getY();
                result=true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                curX= (int)event.getX();
                curY= (int)event.getY();


                result=true;
                break;
        }

        if (result) invalidate();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an user touches that view, it causes the `onTouch` method gets called. Once it's getting called, you're given two `float` numbers: `x` and `y` indicating where user's finger touches your view relative to the view coordination system.

As you might grasped the idea, you should get those numbers and internally in your custom view (i.e. bar chart) calculate which bar is affected. Then, you can for example apply a hover effect or do something else.

**Note:** For updating appearance of your view, you should store changes in data models of your chart view and then issue `invalidate()`. Subsequently, as a result, your `onDraw` is invoked and in which you can re-draw your chart. (i.e. You should each time, re-draw your whole chart again)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have the onTouch for the view currently, as a result whenever the touch event triggers all the bars move together as I get the float numbers : x and y and I add the y value to the top of each bar in the onDraw method and invalidate() so it causes all the bars to move together. I am drawing these rectangles or bars in a for loop in onDraw(). But I am particularly looking for moving each bar separately.

Comment: @SrinivasPillai Please add codes of your chart view.

Comment: @SrinivasPillai Edit your question and add those to your question post.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34248701/edit) your question and add these codes there.